# Inter Community Chatter & User sharing

Tags: community, chatter, customer-community, partner-communities

I am trying to build up a community design where I have multiple sets of users - lets call them CONSUMERS, ORGANISATIONS, PARTNERS, DISTRIBUTORS, PRODUCERS etc. and then we have the INTERNAL employees

Now I want to design separate communities for each sets of users, which is easy in Salesforce so that the INTERNAL EMPLOYEES can collaborate with CONSUMERS, ORGANISATIONS, PARTNERS, DISTRIBUTORS & PRODUCERS

What I also want is that the CONSUMERS should be able to collaborate with ORGANISATIONS, PARTNERS, PRODUCERS & DISTRIBUTORS. The PARTNERS should be able to collaborate with the CONSUMERS< PRODUCERS AND DISTRIBUTORS but nnot ORGANISATIONS.

All the users (CONSUMERS / PARTNERS / ORGANISATIONS) should be able to follow the users that they can collaborate with.

From a UI perspective -

- CONSUMERS should have a separate UI
- ORGANISATIONS should have a
  separate UI
- PARTNERS, PRODUCERS, DISTRIBUTORS should have the similar
  look and feel

Licensing

- CONSUMERS - Customer Community Login License
- PARTNERS - Partner Community License
- OTHERS - Customer Community Plus licenses

I am confused as to should I go with a Single Community and multple profile or multiple communities with their respective profiles or a combination of the two.

I have tried to lay it all out in a diagram

[image: collaboration]

Now I am not sure if all the above has made any sense to you or if you need any more information but any help in this regards as to how I can go about designing this use case would be useful.

Thanks
Vipul

Update - 05/09
What I am really looking for is advice on whether I should use single community for all stakeholders or multiple communities. And If I go via the route of multiple communities, is there a way to share Chatter between the users?

Comment: So what question exactly are you asking?

Comment: apologies fr not making this clearer. what i am really looking for is advice on whether i should go for multiple communities or a single community. and what are the pitfalls for either approach. Regarding the objects - I'd mostly be using custom objects apart from Account/Contact/Case

Comment: If you want your question reopened, I recommend you add this info about the objects to your question as it's very relevant to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you go to the following [Salesforce Page](http://www.salesforce.com/crm/editions-pricing-communities.jsp) and click on Live Chat. I say that because the answers would greatly depend on what objects you want to expose to the various categories you mention.

Also, there's a huge issue with the cost involved that you'll need to consider. Partner licenses are very expensive. If you want all of your customers to be able to talk with your partners, then you'd need to purchase partner licenses for everyone.

This is a very complex question that's far too broad to answer in this venue. You may want to consider hiring an experienced consultant to help guide.

Comment: Thanks @crmprogdev for taking time to respond. I have been pursuing various channels to  find answers to this, but I appreciate your detailed response :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm confident you're learning that this is not a simple question. There are MANY things to consider. You've only provided a very small portion of the relevant info that would be required to determine how best to address this. Its very complex, requires time and expertise that one doesn't impart for free.

Comment: I meant to add that anyplace you want a different UI, you'd need to have a separate community. Otherwise, the JS or JQ to write and serve pages with a different look and feel based on profile/UserId would be very difficult to write and troublesome to manage. Also, you can't mix different licenses within the same community which means you paying for the most expensive license for all users regardless of access level to objects.

Comment: I agree on the UI front. However - I am concerned about sharing Chatter feeds, as the scope of the chatter feeds is limited to the community.

Comment: Regarding different licenses though - I believe you can have different types of licenses added to the same community. The profiles will define the level of access they will have in the community.

Comment: I would check with Salesforce on licensing. When one creates a community, they create a "type" of community, not just a "community" to which they add any license they purchase..